# Scrapy xpath not working

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm pretty new to Scrapy and I was just curious as to why my scraper isn't working. Here is my code:

```
import scrapy

from tutorial.items import TutorialItem

class tutSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "tutorial"
    allowed_domains = ["backpage.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://chicago.backpage.com/FemaleEscorts/naughtiest-_girl-next-door/20557457"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        # sel = response.xpath('//*')
        item = TutorialItem()
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="postingTitle"]/h1/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = response.xpath('a/@href').extract()
        item['desc'] = response.xpath('//body/div[@id="postingBody"]/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

It is yielding the following JSON file:

```
[{"title": [], "link": [], "desc": []}]
```

I'm confident that it is unable to find the specified elements that I'm indicating, even though I'm 100% sure those div IDs are valid. They're within other divs that are within the body.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this basically says **my xpath is not working but I know it is correct**. This is useless for anyone to give an answer without the DOM that it is supposed to match and useless to anyone coming after you with a similar problem because every DOM and xPath will be different so this is extremely localized. Also do not spam the tags with unrelated tags. This is not specific to python in anyway if it is actually bad xPath queries.

Comment: There are plenty of online xPath sites that will actually write an xPath for you for the contents of a given URL.

Answer (score 0):

As you have guessed, problem lies with xpath itself.

for `item['title']`, h1 node is inside an a node which is absent in the xpath you used. so it must be

```
item['title'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="postingTitle"]/a/h1/text()').extract()
item['link'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="postingBody"]/a/@href').extract()
item['desc'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="postingBody"]//text()').extract()
```

As @Jarrod Roberson has pointed out, there are a lot of tools that provide xpaths and validates them

If you're using firefox and firebug, try firepath. Its always good to try out xpaths before putting them in your spider